# char and varchar within the same table

Tags: mysql

Consider this table, where the password is of fixed size and the length of the username varies. I think I've read somewhere that in MySQL, if you use one field of varchar in a table, it's better to exclusively use varchar and not mix char and varchar fields. Is this correct?

```
create table users
(
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, # variable length
password CHAR(60) NOT NULL, # fixed length
PRIMARY_KEY(id),
UNIQUE(username)
);
```

Comment: I usually work with SqlServer, so can't comment on the MySql implementation.  However, your example strikes me as odd - you wouldn't typically have a fixed length field for something like a password, you would usually only used fixed length fields for shorter things like (for example) a postcode.  :)

Comment: @Nathan The passwords are hashed and always of same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differnece is that char will use the entire 60 characters and pad with spaces. varchar does not pad with spaces. There is no reason not to use both if you have reasons for using each for different purposes. Generally though I'd use varchar for both of these.